# White flickering between 2 html Pages

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

i have the problem of a white screen appearing between the transition between 2 separate html pages name index.html and mainpage.html. can anyone please get this to dissapear.i have put in jquery functions to fade in and out! code following :

PS : i am using the windows phone 7 emulator!

HTML:

```
    <a  id="loginbtn" data-role="button" href="MainPage.html" 
style="margin-left: 60px;" class="ui-btn-up-a"> Log in</a>
```

JQuery :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("body").css("display", "none");
        $("body").fadeIn(3000);

        $("a#loginbtn").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            linkLocation = this.href;
            $("body").fadeOut(200, redirectPage);
        });

        function redirectPage() {
            window.location = linkLocation;
        }
    });
```

i have been at the following links, but i am very new to using Cordova/PhoneGap so i dont get this, maybe someone explain it to me will be a great help!

links :

[Github Forums](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4024)

[Github Forums - "Answer"](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/commit/ff1a7e019f45ad00fc9aa3e0fcb08df5acc54a66)

the fadeout works, and the fade in!
but after the fade out the white screen appears and load the new page.

Using : HTML5/CSS/Javascript/Jquerymobile/Jquery.1.7/JqueryMobile.1.2.0

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you expect instead? At the end of page fade out it will indeed be white. Then you do a page refresh and the new page will also start as white ...

Comment: like i said i'm new, so there is no work around for that white screen?  so the app is gonna show a white screen every time a new screen is loaded? cant you at least change the color to match the application's so the transition may look a lot better? and thanks for quick reply

Comment: There is a workaround ... dynamically load new pages using Ajax and then use the built in transitions from jquery-mobile. But this will require you to rebuild your application

Comment: well did not expect that at all! did not know its gonna be this tricky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem is using document.location and efectively restarting the app as Romain pointed out. However, after fixing that, you will still get a blank page but for a different reason.

By default, jquery mobile transitions after 1.1 are sequential (aka horribly broken) - page one fades out, leaving the default white background, then page two fades in. You need to replace the transition handler to get a nice crossfade.

https://github.com/watusi/jquery.mobile.simultaneous-transitions

Comment: awesome! that documentation really worked for me! thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

One of the benefits of using jquery mobile is to have access to its built-in transitions. Instead of manually doing a fade out fade in, you should instead change page by either:

- Simply linking to the target page: JQM allows you to define a transition in a simple link, using the following syntax `<a href="mainpage.html" data-transition="fade">link</a>`. No additional js involved, jqm handles everything, as described and shown [here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-transitions.html)
- Using the $.mobile.changePage() jquery mobile method (in place of setting window.location) and specify the "transition" parameter to the value you want.You do not need to add fade effects manually You can find more details [here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html).

Answer (score 0):

Bypassing the jquery mobile etc, maybe including a background color to your body or html could solve your problem quite easily. Not sure how your design is supposed to be, so feel free to vote my answer down :)

Comment: can i give my html tag in my css this background-color property?? if that is what you mean? :)

Comment: yes you can :) I would suggest something like html, body{background:-whatever-;} (or background-color, of course).

really not sure if that fixes it, but when I put in background images for my mobile projects, they stay there, even when I switch the page.

Comment: but is all of your pages in one html file or seperate?
and no that does not work , or i am doing it wrong?maybe hardcode the backgroundcolor into the html above the page

Comment: as the OP is using `window.location = ...` we can assume that there are separate files

Comment: when you use jquery mobile (as you mentioned), your pages should be on ONE page 
see http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little snippet from CSS-Tricks which allegedly gets rid of IE page flicker:

```
<!-- Stop IE page flicker -->
<!--[if IE]>
    <meta http-equiv="Page-Enter" content="blendTrans(duration=0)" />
    <meta http-equiv="Page-Exit" content="blendTrans(duration=0)" />
<![endif]-->
```

Not sure if it applies to mobile as well as desktop, but it's worth a shot.